# How return values from entire row using .find method (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leNCP.png)I need to return values from entire row as long as it contains "LAB NO." in it. I used `.find` method. My code can return row numbers where the "LAB NO." is found, and now I need to return all the values on that row that follow "LAB NO." cell:
[Source tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqGpY.png)

Here is my code:

```
Sub SearchMe()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim findme As String

findme = "LAB NO."

Dim search As Range
Dim found As Range

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim i As Long

For i = 3 To lastrow
    Set search = sheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
    
    If Not search.Find(what:=findme, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
    
    Set found = search.Find(what:=findme, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    Debug.Print found.Row
       
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I tried create a list/array using .row property so that it looped through rows 10,35 and 67 and returned the three values from each of these rows:

```
Dim r(found.row) as Variant
```

but apparently it doesn't work this way)))

I am new to VBA, still doing a course on it, but we haven't learned about arrays and lists yet.

Comment: Is the result always 3 values?

Comment: Yes, each of the "LAB NO." has three values.

Comment: Will "LAB NO." always be in the first column?

Comment: Yes, "LAB NO." is always in the first column (A) followed by the numbers that I need to return (Columns B,C,D).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the result is always three values, then you can use `Transpose` to create a 1D array.

Also, if you know that "LAB NO." is always in column A, no need to use `Find`.

```
With sheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In sheet.Range("A3:A" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value = "LAB NO." Then
        Dim out As Variant
        out = Application.Transpose(cell.Offset(,1).Resize(,3).Value)
    End If

Next i
```

---

If you're looking to write these to a new column, e.g. column F:

```
With sheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In sheet.Range("A3:A" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value = "LAB NO." Then
         With sheet
             Dim lastRowF As Long
             lastRowF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 
             lastRowF = Application.Max(2, lastRowF)

             Dim out As Variant
             out = Application.Transpose(cell.Offset(,1).Resize(,3).Value)             

            .Cells(lastRowF + 1, "F").Resize(3).Value = out
         End With
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you BigBen! The Transpose printed all three numbers. However It printed the numbers of the last instance of "LAB NO." . How can I make it print transposed numbers stacked on each other of all the instances of "LAB NO." ?

Comment: I mean I want to write them into one column of the same or different sheet (it doesn't matter). Give me a second I will try to attach a picture.

Comment: I added a picture in my original post

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, non-VBA method with `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER($A:$D,$A:$A="LAB NO.")
```

Or if you just want the values:

```
=DROP(FILTER($A:$D,$A:$A="LAB NO."),,1)
or
=FILTER($B:$D,$A:$A="LAB NO.")
```

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just do `=FILTER($B:$D,$A:$A="LAB NO.")`?

Comment: Thank you Kevin! I might also try to do it without VBA.

Comment: Apparantly so! I had never thought to use the "include" criteria outside of the filtered array.

Comment: @Monika if you want these numbers in a single column you can use `TOCOL`

Comment: I didn't know about that function! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Vertically Stack Transposed Matching Rows

[image]

- Since you're looking for matches in a single column, it is more efficient to use `Application.Match` than the *Find* method.

```vb
Sub RetrieveLabNos()
    
    ' Constants
    
    ' The worst way to reference a sheet is using its index, unless
    ' it is a text file (e.g. .csv or .txt can only have one sheet).
    Const SRC_SHEET_ID As Variant = 1 ' better is e.g. "Sheet1", "Data"...
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 3
    Const SRC_TOTAL_COLS As Long = 4
    Const DST_SHEET_ID As Variant = 1 ' better is e.g. "Sheet1", "Data"...
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "F3"
    Const SEARCH_STRING As String = "LAB NO."
    ' If this code is in the workbook containing this sheet,
    ' instead of 'ActiveWorkbook', use 'ThisWorkbook'.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Source Data to Arrays
    
    ' Reference the objects.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_ID)
    Dim srg As Range, rCount As Long
    With sws.UsedRange
        rCount = .Row + .Rows.Count - SRC_FIRST_ROW
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount, SRC_TOTAL_COLS)
    End With
    ' Matches to Array
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = SRC_TOTAL_COLS - 1 ' exclude first column
    Dim Matches() As Variant, MatchesCount As Long
    With Application
        Matches = .Match(srg.Columns(1), Array(SEARCH_STRING), 0)
        MatchesCount = .Count(Matches)
    End With
    If MatchesCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matches found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Source data to Array
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Resize(, cCount).Offset(, 1).Value
    
    ' Source Arrays to Destination Array
    
    ' Define.
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To MatchesCount * cCount, 1 To 1)
    ' Additional variables.
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    ' Source to Destination Array
    For sr = 1 To rCount
        If IsNumeric(Matches(sr, 1)) Then
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dr = dr + 1
                dData(dr, 1) = sData(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Destination Array to Range
    
    ' Reference the objects.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_ID)
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(dr)
    ' Write.
    drg.Value = dData
    ' Clear below.
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Lab numbers retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, thank you very much for your detailed code and explanation to it!